# Is it possible to migrate/move Amazon's EIP from standard to VPC scope?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to migrate/move ElasticIP from standard scope to VPC scope in Amazon Web Services?

I have hundreds of domains pointing to particular EIP and it would be super-sweet if it was possible to attach it to the VPC and not to loose it.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

"When you allocate an EIP [within EC2-classic], it's for use only in EC2-Classic.  When you allocate an EIP [within VPC], it's for use only in a VPC."

Answer (score 2):

You can now move the EIP from standard to vpc scope. Check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#migrating-eip

Answer (score 0):

As of 11/15/2016 this is possible!  \o/\o/\o/

Now is possible move the Elastic IP to "EC2-VPC" scope or restore it to "EC2-Classic" scope.

**Through the AWS Management Console:**

[image: Through the AWS Management Console]

**Through the API (documentation):**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/move-address-to-vpc.html